# Ctrl+C doesn't get registered in python.net

Tags: c#-6.0, python.net

I am using python.net 3.0.0 to execute python scripts from a C# console application. The code looks something like this:

```
public void executePy {
      using (Py.GIL())
                {
                    var pythonThreadID = PythonEngine.GetPythonThreadID();
                    _pythonThreadIds.Add(pythonThreadID);
                    var scope = Py.CreateScope();
                    var file = PythonEngine.Compile(fileContent);
                    scope.Execute(file);

                    dynamic mod = scope.Get("data");


                    mod(abc);
                } }
```

The above code runs in a loop, say every 60 seconds. I have another function in the same class that handles interrupting python threads created by the above code:

```
 public async stopThreads()
{ if (_pythonThreadIds.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var id in _pythonThreadIds)
            {
                using (Py.GIL())
                {
                    PythonEngine.Interrupt(id);
                }

            }
            PythonEngine.EndAllowThreads(_state);

            PythonEngine.Shutdown();
        } }
```

However, whenever the console application executes the executePy code (running in a loop), Ctrl + C isn't registered by the application, but when no python threads are triggered i.e if only C# code is run, ctrl + C is registered and it stops all the existing threads in the console app. Every class has a StopThreads function which is triggered when Ctrl + C is pressed by the user.

These stopThreads functions are executed using a base class that execute different classes and functions within them. the function:

```
public async Task StopThreadClasses()
    {
        try
        {
            // cancel all running processes
            _cts.Cancel();

            foreach (ITB obj in _commandBaseClasses)
            {
                await obj.Stop();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log_message
        }
        finally
        {
            _cts.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this/info will be helpful.